# How to optimize the MySQL query using multiple-column indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, rds

I am very new to MySQL Indexing. I am trying to create Indexes for `web_products` table.
I have created Index `IsDataActive_IsVerified_IsExpired_Price_Sale` to optimize the below query;

```
SELECT 
MAX(Price_Sale) as maxColumn
FROM
`web_products` `t`
WHERE
IsDataActive = 1 AND IsVerified = 1
    AND IsExpired = 0
```

and when I analyze the query using `Explain` I am getting the best possible result `"Select tables optimized away"`.

I have another query which performs very poorly. The `web_products` table may contain millions of products. It takes several minutes to execute the below query;

```
SELECT 
COUNT(P.BrandID)
FROM
web_products AS P
WHERE
P.OriginalItemID IS NULL
    AND P.IsDataActive = 1
    AND P.IsExpired = 0
    AND P.IsVerified = 1;
```

`BrandID` is FK to `brands` table. Here is the [Explain Analysis](https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/?raw_explain=%2B%0D%0A%7Cid%7Cselect_type%7Ctable%7Ctype%7Cpossible_keys%7Ckey%7Ckey_len%7Cref%7Crows%7CExtra%7C%0D%0A%2B%0D%0A%7C1%7CSIMPLE%7CP%7Cref%7CIsDataActive_IsVerified_IsExpired_Price_Sale%2COriginalItemID_IsDataActive_IsExpired_IsVerified%7CIsDataActive_IsVerified_IsExpired_Price_Sale%7C3%7Cconst%2Cconst%2Cconst%7C88331%7CUsing%20where%7C%0D%0A&client=HeidiSQL) for the above query.
How to optimize the above query?

**Update 1**

The `Index` mentioned in the answer is charmingly working for the above queries. I am able to get the results in less than 0.200 ms.

I have modified the second query and added `MerchantID` to the index now it takes 1 second to execute the below query. The Explain shows the number of `rows examined` is `88331`. Is there any way to bring the execution time to milliseconds?

```
SELECT 
P.BrandID, COUNT(P.BrandID) as Count, B.Name
FROM
web_products AS P
    inner join
web_brands as B ON P.BrandID = B.ID
    INNER JOIN
web_merchants M ON P.MerchantID = M.ID
    LEFT JOIN
web_products_features F ON P.ID = F.Product_ID
WHERE
P.OriginalItemID IS NULL
    AND P.IsDataActive = 1
    AND P.IsExpired = 0
    AND P.IsVerified = 1
    AND B.IsDataActive = 1
group by P.BrandID
order by Count desc
Limit 100
```

Comment: LIMIT is pointless here

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks... I understand that. The query was dynamically generated on runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best index for both queries is probably:

```
web_products(IsDataActive, IsExpired, IsVerified, OriginalItemId, BrandId, Price_Sale)
```

The order of the first three columns is unimportant.  This should work for the first query, because it is a covering index.  If it affect performance, then use two indexes and drop `Price_Sale` from this one.

Comment: Hi, this worked for both queries. I have modified the query with few joins. Is there any way to reduce the number of rows examined or the execution time from 1 second? I have updated the question.